# "Simulate" Partial Function Template Specialization?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++17, overloading

I know that partial template specialization does not hold for functions. But is there any way to achieve something similar? My use case is quite simple, but I'm not sure what's the best way to solve it.

Let's say I'm writing a function that takes in an STL container:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T& container) {
    // do something here
}
```

Now, I want a different definition for this function when `std::forward_list` and `std::list` are passed in.

At first I thought perhaps I can overload the function like this:

```
// overload for std::list
template<typename T>
void insertionCppStl(std::list<T>& container) {
    // do seomthing here for list
}
```

But that would mean I need to do the same overload for `std::forward_list` as well. Which is not ideal at all.

Is there any way to overload a function for two different input types? Looking for answers for C++17, but C++20 answer is welcomed as well.

Comment: *But that would mean I need to do the same overload for std::forward_list as well.* You would need to do it for template specializations.

Comment: Step 1/ write a type trait which is true for `list` and `forward_list`, but defaults to false. Step 2/ either have the top-level function dispatch to the "specialization" explicitly with `if constexpr`, or do some SFINAE magic.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution but...

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<C<T>, std::list<T>>
              || std::is_same_v<C<T>, std::forward_list<T>>>
    insertionCppStl (C<T> & container) {
    // do seomthing here for list
}
```

(caution: code not tested)

As pointed by Daniel Langr (thanks!) this works only for lists with standard allocator, so for `std::list<T>` and `std::forward_list<T>`, not for `std::list<T, A>` and `std::forward_list<T, A>` where `A` is an allocator different from `std::allocator<T>`.

This can be enough for you, or not, depending from your needs.

A more generic solution can take in count also the allocator

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename A>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<C<T, A>, std::list<T, A>>
              || std::is_same_v<C<T, A>, std::forward_list<T, A>>>
    insertionCppStl (C<T, A> & container) {
    // do seomthing here for list
}
```

Obviously this works only for `std::list` and `std::forward_list`.

As Barry pointed in a comment (thanks!), a similar solution can be implemented when you have two (three, four...) types with something in common (in this case: template types with compatible signatures) but isn't a general solution.

Unfortunately I don't see a trivial general solution... I propose the development of a specific type_traits to select the accepted types for a specific version of the function.

For example: if you want a specific version for `std::list`s, `std::forward_list`s and `std::array`s, you can write something as follows

```
template <typename>
struct specific_foo : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T, typename A>
struct specific_foo<std::list<T, A>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T, typename A>
struct specific_foo<std::forward_list<T, A>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct specific_foo<std::array<T, N>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

Then two version of the `foo()` function: the specific version (receiving a `std::true_type` as second argument) and a generic one (receiving a `std::false_type`

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T const &, std::false_type)
 { std::cout << "generic version" << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
void foo (T const &, std::true_type)
 { std::cout << "specific version" << std::endl; }
```

Now you need a tag-dispatching version of `foo()` that select the correct type for the second argument

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T const & t)
 { foo(t, specific_foo<T>{}); }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <forward_list>

template <typename>
struct specific_foo : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T, typename A>
struct specific_foo<std::list<T, A>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T, typename A>
struct specific_foo<std::forward_list<T, A>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct specific_foo<std::array<T, N>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T>
void foo (T const &, std::false_type)
 { std::cout << "generic version" << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
void foo (T const &, std::true_type)
 { std::cout << "specific version" << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
void foo (T const & t)
 { foo(t, specific_foo<T>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   foo(0);                             // print "generic version"
   foo(std::list<int>{});              // print "specific version"
   foo(std::forward_list<long>{});     // print "specific version"
   foo(std::array<long long, 42u>{});  // print "specific version"
   foo(std::vector<char>{});           // print "generic version"
 }
```

Comment: @DanielLangr - good point; answer improved; thanks.

Comment: Although now it doesn't work `std::map`, `llvm::SmallVector`, or user-defined containers that might not have any template parameters

Comment: @Barry - Right: isn't a generic solution. Unfortunately, I don't see a trivial generic solution. The best that come in my mind at the moment pass through tag dispatching. Anyway... answer improved.

Comment: Thanks @max66, would it be better to do this instead? ```template <typename T> enable_if_t<specific_foo<T>::value> foo (T const & t)```